# How to run grid-search for custom estimator which has a custom pipeline?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to run grid-search for a custom case that involves a estimator that contains `pipeline` as one of its constructor input.

```
class DefaultEstimator(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
  def __init__(self, preprocessor, pipelines):
    self.pipelines = pipelines

  def fit(self, X, y=None):
    for idx, each_pipeline in enumerate(self.pipelines):
      each_pipeline.fit(X[idx], y)
    return self

  def transform(self, X):
   transformed_data = []
   for idx, each_pipeline in enumerate(self.pipelines):
     transformed_data.append(each_pipeline.transform(X[idx))
   return sp.hstack(transformed_data)
```

My pipeline looks something like this:

```
pipeline1 = trainer.create_pipeline(num_features=100)
pipeline2 = trainer.create_pipeline(num_features=50)
```

Composite pipeline looks like:

```
aggregated_pipeline = Pipeline([('contextual', DefaultEstimator([pipeline1, pipeline2])),
                                ('classifier', Pipeline([('clf', SVM(random_state=1234, probability=True)]))
                              ])
```

Input data has two columns and for each column, there is a respective pipeline (`pipeline1` and `pipeline2`) respectively.

The keys for `grid_params` for `clf` can be written as `classifier__clf__C`, `classifier__clf__gamma` etc.

The question is: How to write `grid_params` for `GridSearchCV(...)` as one of the pipeline steps isn't a pipeline object rather a custom-estimator object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GridSearchCV` and `Pipeline` use the estimator's `set_params` to set the parameters to test. So, you have to implement this in your `DefaultEstimator`, and set the pipeline parameters appropriately. A common pattern in scikit is to use double underscore to separate parameters of nested objects, so for example:

```
class DefaultEstimator:
    def set_params(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            parts = k.split('__')
            if parts[0].startswith('pipeline'):
                pipe_num = int(parts[0].split('_')[1])
                param_name = '__'.join(parts[1:])
                self.pipelines[pipe_num].set_params(*{param_name: v})
            else:
                # other logic
```

This would allow you to use parameters such as `contextual__pipeline_1__num_features` (`contextual__` will be stripped away by the grid search, so no need to handle it).

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much @BlackBear